# How to use reroute in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

For example i have URI `/index.php/system/index/page/5`, is it possible to reroute that it would look like `index.php/page/5`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do this in application/config/routes.php.  You would do

```
$route['page/5'] = "system/index/page/5";
```

If you are going to use this same url strucuture multiple times, like

```
/index.php/system/index/page/1
/index.php/system/index/page/2
/index.php/system/index/page/3
```

Then you can do

```
$route['page/(:num)'] = "system/index/page/$1";
```

Comment: is it possible to catch `$1` in model?

Comment: @Kirix the `$1` will be passed to the controller method, you can then pass it on to anuy model you like..

Comment: @Kirix Can I also ask is there a reason why you have index.php in the URL? It look nicer if you hide this and its also better for security because people won't be able to tell that you're using php.  If you want to hide it, this can be done in the .htaccess file